# jQuery UI Calendar displays too large, would like the demo size?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui

So I downloaded a custom themed UI for jQuery and added the calendar control to my site (Example: [link text](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)). In the example it shows/displays the size I would like but on my webpage it's about twice the size. why???

I do have a ton of other CSS but I don't have control over the look and feel of the page (Can't touch current CSS, MEH!!). Is there a way to get the demo look on my site?

I think this is the code that jQuery UI has that might be complicating things

```
/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em; }
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #B9C4CE; background: #ffffff url(../images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #616161; }
.ui-widget-content a { color: #616161; }
.ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #467AA7; background: #467AA7 url(../images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_467AA7_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; }
.ui-widget-header a { color: #fff; }
```

It's part of the Custom UI CSS

Comment: but looks like the demo has a strike through as well

Comment: I know, this question is more than a year old, but it's been very useful to me, thanks!

Comment: Ditto, just found this and needed it. Yay Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I figured it out. It was the font size that was throwing the whole thing off. I added this tag to correctly display the size I wanted:

```css
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size: 12px; }
```

Works great if anyone else needs something like this

Comment: Future note: Use the ui-widget class instead, as this issue impacts other widgets. `.ui-widget   { font-size: 12px; }`

Comment: Changing it to 12px; did not work for me.  I had to change it to .6em

Comment: @Incognito it didn't work change the .ui-widget for me. Had to change as Phill said.

Comment: hurray!! SharePoint 2010 somehow changed the font size and caused this issue. This solved it. Thanks!

Comment: What if you have more than one datepicker on the page - not sure why there is even an "id" property on this, given that multiple datepickers is surely common.  Seems like at least it should be applied to the class and not the id.

Comment: @sydneyos - It only uses 1 datepicker instance, since it only shows 1 datepicker at a time, so it doesn't need to create additional datepickers for each calendar you have showing.  Therefore, the id value is acceptable and validates perfectly fine...

Answer (score 9):

```css
.ui-widget{ font-size: 0.8em; }
```

That is the solution, but, what I didn't know is if you put it into the head element like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-widget { font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em; }
</style>
```

**It overrides other settings**, so you can still load the google hosted css but use this to override it =)

Comment: only if you put it after the css link. It has to come lower on the page so it overrides. Defining this before the CSS link will have no effect.

Comment: +1: as jcolebrand said, we need to put it after, but we can use the version google-hosted.

Answer (score 8):

To fix the size of the calendar control change this:

```css
.ui-widget { font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.1 em; }
```

to this:

```css
.ui-widget { font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em; }
```

For detailed instructions please visit - http://blog.greatdevelopers.com/?p=33

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set font size or font family for all of jQuery's widgets, it would be better to set something like this:

```css
.ui-widget {
    font-size: .7em;
}
```

after the call to load jQuery UI CSS files.

All jQuery UI components are widgets and inherit the `.ui-widget` style at the top level.

Answer (score 1):

A DOM inspector (e.g., Firebug, IE Developer Toolbar, etc.) should help you determine which CSS styles are affecting your calendar.

Perhaps whichever party is barring you from touching the CSS would allow you free reign within a container? I.e.,

```
<div id="foo">Your stuff goes here. All your selectors must start with #foo</div>
```

If not, you apparently have control over the JS. You should be able to write inline styles with that.

EDIT

You might also see if you can get your content wrapped in an iframe.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why I respond at all - someone always beats me to the punch, and usually with a better answer!

Comment: Looks like some of the CSS has a strike through it:

See edit post

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure what you mean. Can you be more specific? I don't see the strike-through or have any <strike> tags in my post.

Answer (score 1):

In order for me to make my calendar smaller I had to make a few more changes to the css.
As some other people already mentioned I added the following line to a style tag inside my page (so it doesn't affect all the other date pickers on my site)

```
div.ui-datepicker{ font-size:7px;}
```

But this only made the title size smaller (month year).  In order to make the weekday labels and day numbers smaller I had to also copy the following two lines out of the jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css and put them in my page, but then I also had to add the font-size specs for both.

```
.ui-datepicker th { padding: .7em .3em; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; border: 0;}
.ui-datepicker td { border: 0; padding: 1px; }
```

So what I ended up with is the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.ui-datepicker{ font-size:7px;}
.ui-datepicker th { padding: .7em .3em; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; border: 0; font-size: 1.6em;}
.ui-datepicker td { border: 0; padding: 1px; font-size: 1.6em;}
</style>
```

This allows me to control the font size for date & year, weekday labels, and date numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to use

```
.ui-datepicker { font-size:10px !important; }
```

instead of using

```
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size:10px !important; }
```

because css class selectors have wider scope as compare to using element selectors which are only for specific element. All you need to do is create another html element of the class type and you don't have to worry about anything at all.

However in your issue you don't have to do anything just add the class selector to your own css file NOT the one for jquery-ui, and you're sorted, if you need to create another datepicker you will not have to worry about modifying the css again this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS zoom

```
.ui-widget{ 
    -ms-transform: translate(-15%,-15%) scale(0.7);//translate must be before scale
    -moz-transform: translate(-15%,-15%) scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-15%,-15%) scale(0.7);
    transform: translate(-15%,-15%) scale(0.7);
}
```

In the code above, I have used "sclale(0.7)" which means that the new width and height will be 70% of the original values. The element after  transformation **will have the same center** of the original element, therefore reducing 30% of the width which means reducing 15% from the left and 15% from the right, the same thing for the height. So we have to use translate to move the new element to the top left. "translate" must be before "scale" so "15%" will be 15% of the original width (i.e. before we scale) and not of the new width after the transformation.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm. Now I just need to center it. It's in the lower right of the div I want it to center in, but looks great!!

Comment: @clearlight FYI: I have edited the answer by adding a code to center it.

Comment: Why are you using a fixed constant and not something proportional or a 2d translate() or translate-origin? i tried messing with it today but still couldn't figure out exactly why it was scaling toward the lower right corner or what ratios applied. I did a hacky manipulation but I'd rather vet the mat and relationships right and understand it better if possible rather than hack it.

Comment: @clearlight FYI: I have improved the answer using your suggestions. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have css conflicts on your page - for example html/body or container font-size settings that would flow down to the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever size you want You can set by editing this line in css.

```
.ui-widget { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em; }
```

just give another font size like .5em or .8em

```
 .ui-widget { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: .5em; }
```

It will work, I have dont it.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple : Jquery-ui just do his job using object style.  I mean :

```
<html>
   <body
     <input type="text" id="date"/>
     <script type="text/javascript"> $("#date").datepicker()</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The size of date number and munth name will be set in function of the : $("#date").css("font-size").   So, if the input has 6px as font-size, datepicker will look small.  If font-size is 42pt, it will be a blind's date picker!

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to stumble across this, but try adding the DOCTYPE html to your document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

before your opening html tag.